# How can I parameterize an Eclipse generated make file

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have an Eclipse CDT project that is configured to generate make files.

I am developing on windows at the moment, and my build server is running Linux.

The make files build well on my local machine, but I have two pre-built external dependencies: boost and ZeroMQ. Both of these have an include directory, a lib directory and an associated dll/so.

How can I configure the project such that the generated make files can have different BOOST_HOME or ZMQ_HOME variables that are resolved at make time (as opposed to being baked into the make file).

Comment: Just a quick and dirty alternative to touching the Makefile. You could have symbolic links in the projects, and change what they point to based on the platforms.

Comment: I need this to translate to a non-eclipse environment for the build server. How does eclipse render the symbolic links to the make file?

Comment: The makefiles will probably refer to the symbolic links as folders in the project folder hierarchy. So you can change where they point to in Linux, obtaining the effect you desire.

Comment: enobayram, I am shooting for a solution that works for windows or linux (as well as in the IDE or shell). I'm not sure what the eclipse symbolic links do on windows.

Comment: symbolic links have nothing to do with eclipse, they're basically fake files/folders, that simply point to a real file/folder somewhere else. Both Linux and Windows (at least 7) support them. If you use them to point to whatever directory you might want, eclipse will not even know about it. It will naively use that fake folder, which in reality points to the right folder in each platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Makefiles generated by CDT include the following lines:

```
-include ../makefile.init
 ...
-include ../makefile.defs
 ...
-include ../makefile.targets
```

That is, you can add e.g. `makefile.defs` in the project root to control the build.

JeffV Edit:
I added a makefile.init:

```
 BOOST_HOME = C:\code\boost_1_48_0
 ZMQ_HOME = C:\code\zmq\zeromq-2.1.11
```

In the project settings "Build Variables" config I also added these entries:

```
BOOST_HOME = $(BOOST_HOME)
ZMQ_HOME = $(ZMQ_HOME)
```

Which causes eclipse to replace ${BOOST_HOME} where it is references in my lib and include paths, with the $(BOOST_HOME) variable in the make file.

This allows me to have a platform specific version of the makefile.init on each build platform.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on how to override a path variable.

Comment: @Jeff, something like `export PATH := your/path:$(PATH)` in makefile... Or, alternatively, `PATH` can be set through Eclipse project properties: C/C++ Build -> Environment

Comment: I still don't get what I need to add to the makefile.init and how to configure eclipse to render the makefile with the a build variable at some point.