# How to build PCL+OpenCV+OpenNI project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opencv, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

I have successfully configured the includes and libs in order to build OpenCV and OpenNI in Eclipse under OS X. However now I need to add the PCL libraries. I tried to do it the same way but 1- there're a lot of files, 2- I get [614 errors](http://pastebin.com/6DadfdPR) after adding the libraries.

I have the CMakeLists.txt with which I am able to build PCL project.

```
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

Could I add somehow this Cmake to existing configuration of OpenCV+OpenNI which already works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the errors you get, it seems that you have not linked to some of the dependencies, for example `VTK`. I don't think it has nothing to do with `OpenCV` or `OpenNI`.

Edit: I don't see any `VTK` in your screenshots. You should include the headers folder path in the `Include` section, the libraries folder path in the `Library search path` section and the libraries themselves in the `Libraries` section (in the same place where in your screenshot you have `libpcl_visualization` etc). (*Disclaimer: I am not using Eclipse, I am guessing those from your screenshots, if I am wrong edit my answer*)

Note that since you are not using CMake you will probably have to do that for the other dependencies too sooner or later (e.g. Boost etc)

Comment: I know about that. I have checked the CMakeCache file to get the dependencies.I'm building with [following](http://pastebin.com/s75geZfR) command configured on Eclipse:

Comment: @vitalikox Yeap, but have you installed the 3rd party libs mentioned in the above link before doing that? (VTK,boost,Eigen etc)

Comment: Of course. I have all installed. I can build/run PCL projects but generated with CMakeLists.txt I use. Not in Eclipse.

Comment: Do you link to the VTK libs when you build it without CMake?

Comment: I'm trying to link that but not sure if I do it right way

[image1](http://i037.radikal.ru/1210/c0/be7c9d9496f5.jpg)
[image2](http://s019.radikal.ru/i644/1210/f2/6fbadab8c048.jpg)
[image3](http://s47.radikal.ru/i115/1210/e6/6dfa463d08b3.jpg)

Comment: SOLVED This goes to Include section of Eclipse /opt/local/include/vtk-5.10

Comment: How could I remember/export this Eclipse build configuration and use it for other projects?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705947/with-eclipse-how-to-add-include-paths-and-libraries-for-all-your-c-project) describes exactly what you want to do, right?

Comment: @vitalikox Out of curiosity, why don't you use CMake for that? Doesn't it automatically create an Eclipse project with everything linked?

Comment: Because I don't manage that. I just have my CMakeLists.txt which generates all I need with "cmake . && make" command. Then I run simply ./program. I would like to learn how to generate for eclipse directly.  Also I just wanted to learn how to add libraries and include dirs to Eclipse