# Add library from path for C project

Tags: c, eclipse

I want to add a library to my project which is located at

```
/somepath/my/library/library.h
```

(Linux system). In my project I only want to write something like this

```
#include "library.h"
```

and eclipse shall include this without errors... How do that?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I've tried to add an "Library-Path" in Properties->C/C++ general->Paths and Symbols and also to add an Preprocessor Include...

Comment: check here once....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705947/with-eclipse-how-to-add-include-paths-and-libraries-for-all-your-c-c-project

Comment: your statement: /somepath/my/library/library.h is to a header file, not a library file.  a library file will have a format such as liblibrary.a

Comment: in gcc, (similar function in eclipse) the line would be: gcc File.c -o File.o -L/somepath/my/library -llibrary -I/somepath/my/library -I.  where the -L gives the path to your library and -I give the path to your header file