# Using Botan library with Eclispse

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors, botan

I am trying to use botan library with eclipse. I have compiled botan using Ubuntu and I created small program as follow

```
#include <botan/botan.h>
int main()
{
    LibraryInitializer init;
    return 0;
}
```

But I have got fatal error: `botan/build.h: No such file or directory`

Thanks in advance and waiting for help.

Comment: See [Adding Include paths and symbols](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm) in Eclipse Help Center and [With Eclipse: How to add include paths and libraries for all your C/C++ project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2705947/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your gcc command line the `-lbotan` option in order to compile correctly.