# Eclipse CDT not generating symbols for new projects

Tags: c++, eclipse, symbols, eclipse-cdt

All new projects I create in eclipse lack any automatic includes (such as the standard library) or any of the default Paths and Symbols that are usually generated automatically. The only way I can get my new projects to work is to manually copy the paths and symbols, as well as the includes, to the other project. This is very tedious and isn't practical. Is there any way to restore those Paths and Symbols, as well as the includes, as the default?

Edit: This is the export file that gets created (with not data):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cdtprojectproperties>
<section name="org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.wizards.settingswizards.IncludePaths">
<language name="Object File">

</language>
<language name="Assembly Source File">

</language>
<language name="C++ Source File">

</language>
<language name="C Source File">

</language>
</section>
<section name="org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.wizards.settingswizards.Macros">
<language name="Object File">

</language>
<language name="Assembly Source File">

</language>
<language name="C++ Source File">

</language>
<language name="C Source File">

</language>
</section>
</cdtprojectproperties>
```

Comment: Are you looking for more than the `Import Settings...` and `Export Settings...` buttons under `Paths and Symbols` in the project properties? Or, if you're not using them, maybe they would suffice.

Comment: @tenterhook I have tried them. For some reason, they export xml files with no data, and do not transfer any symbols to the other project.

Comment: The export file was 0 bytes long or had something in it but just not the actual settings? The first would be a major bug (obviously). The second happens if the settings are exported before they are `apply`-ed to the project. It seems reasonable that nothing exported means nothing imported, so hopefully it's just an export-side problem.

Comment: @tenterhook The problem seems to be the second one. I posted the file it created above.

Comment: @tenterhook The thing is, when I uncheck "show built-in values" all the Paths and Symbols as well as the includes disappear. Could this be related to the problem? Does eclipse somehow think that those values are being applied to all projects already?

Comment: The file you posted is what I get when I export settings from a project with no settings to export, which seems to tie into your next comment about unchecking "show built-in values". Under `Paths and Symbols` -> `References`, is anything checked?

Comment: @tenterhook No, nothing is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative to the `Export/Import Settings` buttons that I stumbled upon while looking into the export problem you're having. It's actually a process that I think I'll be using from now on, so if nothing else I learned something from answering your question. There may be a cleaner or quicker way of doing the same thing, but this at least works.

- Open Eclipse preferences and navigate to `C/C++`→`Property Pages Settings`. Check `Display "Export Settings" tab`.
- Create a new `C++ Project` that will represent your settings. `Empty Project` with your preferred toolchain works, but I doubt it matters what you choose.
- Open this settings project's properties and navigate to `C/C++ General`→`Export Settings`.
- Add your common include folders & files, symbols, libraries and library paths here.
- Open your normal C++ project's properties and navigate to `Paths and Symbols`→`References`. Check the box next to the name of your new settings project.
- The export settings assigned in your settings project now appear in your normal project.

Now whenever you need those settings again, just import that settings project into your workspace and have the other projects reference it.

Let me know if this works for you. I'm still fiddling with it (there are quite a few new options available that open up with this approach), so any feedback would be great.

---

*Edit*: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942562/1201210) describes an alternative way to share settings between projects. It may work better for you if you don't like the "project as settings" thing I describe here.