# Eclipse CDT Getting path & symbols from referenced project

Tags: eclipse, import, path, reference, eclipse-cdt

I added a project as referenced project (with active configuration) to my actual project.
My expectation was that all the symbols and includes defined in that project should also be accessible in my actual project, but unfortunately that is not the case.

I aslo expected that the include pathes and symbols are detected by the Exported Entries from referenced Project providers. But there are no entries found by them.

Is my expectation wrong, or is there a problem with my confinguration?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For importing the Path & Symbols from external projects, the export property (button) has to be set.
See also question:
["Export" button in Eclipse CDT "Paths and Symbols" dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790631/export-button-in-eclipse-cdt-paths-and-symbols-dialog)?